# Is it possible to insert data into table using two select statements in one query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with databases in which I have 3 tables one is `skill` table the other one is `experience` and the third one is `Experience_skill` table in this table I have foreign keys now the question is both foreign keys are primary keys as well. Let say I am storing data into skill table as well as in experience table how can I insert the the both keys data there in `Experience_skill` table. I have tried following queries.

```
insert into Experience_skill(eid, Skill_Id)
select eid 
from Experience 
where eid=2 
union
select Skill_Id 
from Skills 
where Skill_Id=2
```

error I get:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
>   Than i tried this one.

```
insert into Experience_skill(eid)select eid from Experience where eid=2
```

it gives me this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Skill_Id', table 'resume.dbo.Experience_skill'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   Please help me out
>   here are the snapshots of the table first snap shot is of skill table[image]

the second one is experience table [image]

And this one is `EXperience_skill` table where  i have my foreign keys[image]

Comment: Please provide DDLs for your tables.

Comment: I don't think union is what you're looking for here. you need to specify as many columns in the select as in the insert

Comment: in the insert you're saying you'll provide eid and Skill_Id.. however your select is only providing one of those.

Comment: i dont know i am messing up with this kind of problem first time

Comment: Also, you're trying to insert eid and skill_id but you're providing those both in the where clause.... in other words.. you already have what you're looking for.

Comment: what do you mean by ddls sorry i cant understand ddls

Comment: He wants to see your junk.

Comment: i dont think so @samyi

Comment: He wants to see your table structure... aka... junk. ;)  DDL = Data Definition Language.

Comment: Thats why i am here the main problem is how to retrieve from both table and insert into one and i think it cannt be handle with join also

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Insert a row for every skill/experience combination? Or what?

Comment: ok but i can not post the snapshot because of my reputation i have tried to upload the snapshot but i couldnt

Comment: ok let me explain i want that when i submit data to those two table exprience and skill and i have foreign keys in other table belongs to those two tables i want the keys values upload there when submitting the data to those two table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using INSERT INTO, you need to supply ALL of the columns in the destination table (that do not allow NULLs) in each ROW of the SELECT.

Comment: you are saying this,insert into Experience_skill(eid, Skill_Id)select eid from Experience where eid=2 UNION select Skill_Id from Skills where Skill_Id=2

Comment: i think this will work if i create the view of both tables and than i apply the above query

Comment: no, that will not work. In your example, each row will only have 1 column in it, either eid or Skill_id.  You need to have eid AND Skill_id in the same row.

Comment: oh i see so it is not possible to have the single row in select statement . so there is no way to that any idea i am really needing this

Comment: the reason why we all want to see your table structure is to determine if there is some relationship between the 2 tables.  If there is, then they can be JOINed in a single query to produce what you need.

Comment: you should probably edit the original post, and stick it there.  It will come out very messy in a comment.

Comment: I have just added the snap shots